# Entity 'models\ForgottenLogin' has a composite identifier but uses an ID generator other than manually assigning (Identity, Sequence)

Tags: php

When I try to do this

```
 $forgottenLoginRepo = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('models\ForgottenLogin');
            $forgottenLogin = $forgottenLoginRepo->findOneBy(
                array(
                    'passwordKey' => $key

                )
            );
```

I get this error

> Entity 'models\ForgottenLogin' has a composite identifier but uses an
>   ID generator other than manually assigning (Identity, Sequence). This
>   is not supported.

My model is

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Manisha.DeSilva
 * Date: 06/07/2017
 * Time: 13:03
 */

namespace models;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="park_forgotten_login")
 *
 */

class ForgottenLogin
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($value)
    {
        $this->id = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer")
     * @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customer;

    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    public function setCustomer($value)
    {
        $this->customer = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @Column(name="password_Key", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $passwordKey;

    public function getPasswordKey()
    {
        return $this->passwordKey;
    }

    public function setPasswordKey($value)
    {
        $this->passwordKey = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @Column(name="expiry", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $expiry;

    public function getExpiry()
    {
        return $this->expiry;
    }

    public function setExpiry($value)
    {
        $this->expiry = $value;
    }

    private $forgottenFlag;

    public function getForgottenFlag()
    {
        return $this->forgottenFlag;
    }

    public function setForgottenFlag($value)
    {
        $this->forgottenFlag = $value;
    }


}
```